# Android custom camera api shoot pictures with custom png as background

Tags: android, android-camera

I want make an Android app with custom camera API, which can take pictures with some png files as frames(Like some web came apps in PCs). And also first I want to take a picture of ball(or something) which act as frame for the second photo that I am going to take. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Most devices already have a camera application, which you can start for the result if that suits your requirement. 
But if you have more extensive requirement android also allows you to directly control the camera. Directly controlling the camera is much more involved and you should access your requirement before deciding on either approach. 
You can refere to the following develper guides to get details of both

- http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Once you get the Bitmap, you can use the canvas element to combine the two bitmaps.

Comment: I'm fine with the default camera...But ho do we merge one png and other image to be taken??

Comment: updated the answer : Once you get the Bitmap, you can use the canvas element to combine the two bitmaps.

Comment: Got the merging part.

Comment: It would be great if you can add it to the answer so that people who are searching for the same thing can find it.